# select * from c where salary in (select salary from c order by salary desc group by rownum salary having rownum=2);

Tags: sql, oracle

I want second highest salary form this query

```
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE salary IN (
        SELECT salary
        FROM c
        ORDER BY salary DESC
        GROUP BY rownum salary
        HAVING rownum = 2
        );
```

> Error: Missing Expression

Comment: where is your table name ?

Comment: Select * from c where salary in (select salary from c order by salary desc group by rownum having rownum=2);      try this

Comment: What's the expected result if the salaries are 10, 10, 9, 8 ...? I.e a tie.

Comment: Is `c` the name of your table ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a rank analytic function here, e.g.

```
SELECT salary
FROM
(
    SELECT salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) dr
    FROM c
) t
WHERE dr = 2;
```

This would return the second highest salary by dense rank, including all ties for second.

Comment: This is much the better solution, because you can return other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation why your subquery can't work:

1. At first, records are read from the table in an arbitrary order. This is when they get their `rownum`.
2. Then aggregation takes place; all records for one `salary` are condensed to a single row. The `rownum` of the single rows you had before are no longer available.
3. Then the aggregated rows are filtered by `HAVING`, and this cannot work, as you are trying to access `rownum`. Moreover, conditions on `rownum = 2` always fail, because you are dismissing the first row, so it is "not read" and `rownum` 1 is still available, you dismiss the second, because you haven't even read `rownum` 1 yet, and so on. Criteria on `rownum` is always `rownum <= some_number` (except for 1 where you can have `rownum = 1`).
4. The last thing that happens is the sorting; the `ORDER BY` clause belongs at the end of the query hence. (It can only be followed by `FETCH FIRST n ROWS` as of Oracle 12c.)

Here is how to make it work with `rownum`:

```
select salary
from
(
  select salary
  from
  (
    select distinct salary 
    from c
    order by salary desc
  )
  where rownum <= 2
  order by salary
)
where rownum = 1;
```

This works, because Oracle is violating the SQL standard here. According to the standard, data from subqueries is considered unordered, but Oracle guarantees the order when working with `rownum`.

Here is how to do it with aggregation:

```
select max(salary) from c where salary < (select max(salary) from c);
```

Since Oracle 10 you can also use analytic functions as shown in Tim's answer.